# How to reshape a dataframe into a particular format

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, transform, reshape

I have the following dataframe which I want to reshape:

```
    year    control   Counts_annee_control
0   2014.0  0         81.0
1   2016.0  1         147.0
2   2016.0  0         168.0
3   2015.0  1         90.0
4   2016.0  1         147.0
```

I want the `control` column to be the new index, so I will have only two columns. The `year` values should be the new columns of the dataframe and finally the `Counts_annee_control` column will fill the dataframe.

I tried using `groupby` and `transform` but I don't think I'm doing it correctly.

Comment: `control` can't be the index because it contains duplicate values

Comment: Have you tried `df = df.set_index("control")`?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html).

If `df` is your DataFrame, then this

```
modified_df = df.pivot_table(
    values='Counts_annee_control', index='control', columns='year'
)
```

will result in

```
year     2014.0  2015.0  2016.0
control                        
0          81.0     NaN   168.0
1           NaN    90.0   147.0
```